# Searching In datagridview in Windows Application VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview

I have to filter datagridview using textbox.The code below I am using to fill gridview.getdata function of db class returns the datatable.

I am not using datasource property of gridview instead I am filing gridview using loop.

I can do searching using datasource property and dataview but i have not to fill datagridview directly from datasource property.

```
Sub griddesgn()
    DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("crime", "crime")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("actname", "actname")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("section", "section")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("description", "description")
End Sub

Private Sub TEST_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    griddesgn()
    Dim DBOBJ As New db
    Dim DTT As DataTable = DBOBJ.getdata("SELECT crime,actname,section,description from natureofcomplaint_women")

    If DTT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To DTT.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("crime").Value = DTT.Rows(i).Item("crime") & ""
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("actname").Value = DTT.Rows(i).Item("actname") & ""
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("section").Value = DTT.Rows(i).Item("section") & ""
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("description").Value = DTT.Rows(i).Item("description") & ""
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, this is unclear for me. You mention searching in your title, but you (implicitly) talk about using the `ItemsSource` in your question.

Comment: I am programatically filling data in gridview using for loop from datatable dt returned by getdata function.Now the data should be filtered as soon as i start typing in textbox shown.Thats It...

Comment: Bind the DataTable to the DataGridView with a BindingSource. Then, use the Filter property of the BindingSource.

Comment: "If DTT.Rows.Count > 0 Then" is not necesary.

Comment: It works fine using binding source.But i am filling the data in gridview programaticaly using for loop insteead using Datagridview1.Datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WHERE statement in your SQL Query

```
"SELECT crime,actname,section,description from natureofcomplaint_women WHERE crime = " & txtSearch.text
```

(If you want to search on crime.)
Change to your needs.
Just repeat the datagrid fill you used above, but with an altereted SQL query each time you type/press the search button

Answer (score 0):

I still think it's best to bind...

```
Sub griddesgn()
DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("crime", "crime")
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("actname", "actname")
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("section", "section")
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("description", "description")
End Sub

Private Sub TEST_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    griddesgn()
    Dim DBOBJ As New db
    Dim DTT As DataTable = DBOBJ.getdata("SELECT crime,actname,section,description from natureofcomplaint_women")

    Dim source1 as New BindingSource()
    source1.DataSource = DTT
    source1.Filter = "crime = '" & textboxtCrime.text & "'"
    DataGrideView1.DataSource = source1

End Sub
```

Comment: It works fine but i have to apply some formating on the data returned from datatable.thats y i am using for loop to fill the gridview.

Comment: Okay, if you must use a for loop you could contain the copying portion of it inside an If block that includes only rows that match all criteria:  I'll post another answer below in a few mins with an example.

Comment: please post your answer..waiting 4 ur response

Comment: I already posted the second answer days ago... it's below this one

Comment: THIS ONE NOT FULFILL THE REQUIREMENT.

Comment: Please suggest any solution which programatically fills the grid using for loop and then apply filteration on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub griddesgn()
    DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("crime", "crime")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("actname", "actname")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("section", "section")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("description", "description")
End Sub

Private Sub TEST_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    griddesgn()
    Dim DBOBJ As New db
    Dim DTT As DataTable = DBOBJ.getdata("SELECT crime,actname,section,description from natureofcomplaint_women")

    If DTT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
       For i As Integer = 0 To DTT.Rows.Count - 1
        If  (DTT.Rows(i).Item("Crime").Contains(txtCrimeFilter.Text) AND & _
                (DTT.Rows(i).Item("actname").Contains(txtActnameFilter.Text) AND & _
                (DTT.Rows(i).Item("section").Contains(txtSectionFilter.Text)     AND & _
                (DTT.Rows(i).Item("description").Contains(txtDescriptionFilter.Text)
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("crime").Value = DTT.Rows(i).Item("crime") & ""
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("actname").Value = DTT.Rows(i).Item("actname") & ""
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("section").Value = DTT.Rows(i).Item("section") & ""
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("description").Value = DTT.Rows(i).Item("description") & ""
        End If
    Next
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: This assumes you have a filter textbox for each of the 4 columns... if not, then remove them.  Also, the filter above is case sensitive... if you don't want that either, then just .ToUpper both the row item and the textbox.text

Comment: Exactly what part of the requirement does this not fulfill?  It's programatically filling the datagridview and applying filter.